# How to add an item in a new line in layout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am new at development in Android Studio. I want to add new boxes to the line below if the first row is full. In the image below, items #1,#2,#3,#4 are filling the whole width and so when I add a new item (box #5) it goes next to box #4. How can I add it to the second row automatically?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:padding="1dp">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:text="#test_hashtag"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_text_bg"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="13dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

circle_text_bg is drawing a border line on the boxes.

What I did try:
I tried using a RecyclerView and a ListView instead of a TextView. But all of them go horizontally **or** vertically only.

Edit1: The items are dynamic. They are some hashtags (that means the first line might contain 3 items and the second might contain 4 items... etc.)

Comment: RecyclerView has a GridLayoutManager. You can specify the column count and it'll automatically take care of positioning items.

Comment: oh my friend you save my day. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a RecyclerView with the [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager).

If you want four columns, you can do something like this:

```
GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(context, 4);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(glm);
```

Or, in XML:

```
<RecyclerView
    ...
    app:spanCount="4"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager"
    />
```

(`androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager` if you use AndroidX)

Comment: is it possible to make dynamic instead of giving specific column number on new GridLayoutManager(context, XXX); ?